# ASUS T300 CHI function keys and scrolling not working

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, asus, scrolling

I have the asus t300 chi computer dual booted with 16.04 LTS version. I have installed all the regular updates as they arrive. However the function keys and the touchpad functions such as left and right finger scrolling do not work. The sound functions (f10-f12) are working. Are there any fixes for this issue available yet?

Answer (score 0):

I believe i wrote this question when using 16.04 and then upgrading to 17.10 which didnt resolve the issue. After much trial and error with suggested fixes, after updating to the newest version 18.04 I think, the touchpad now works pretty much as it does in windows 10.  I still need  to check whether the function keys work as there was a problem with that and also I couldnt boot into safe mode. Thanks to all the coders that helped resolve the problem. woodo